# Java Scanner, how to split this input text file properly with multiple whitespaces in between?

Tags: java

So i had this file given:

```
A-4     09-20-2083  B/2
A/4     04/27/2048  C-2
A/2b     1/24/75    A/4b
A/4     05/07/2049  A/2b
A/2b     7/ 3/31    B/2
A/2b     5/11/53    B-4b
C-4     14-07-2051  A/2
C-2b    22-12-44    A/4
C-4b    11-11-2055  C.2
A/2b     5/11/16    C-2
C.4     08.01.2058  A-4b
B-4b    2010-11- 2  B/2b
B/2b    26/ 3/13    A-4b
C-2     18-06-06    B-4
C.2     08.08.09    C-2
A/2     01/20/99    B-2b
C.4     18.08.2077  B/2
A-4b    10-21-2086  B/4b
B/2b    50/ 2/ 5    A/2
A/4     03/08/2001  A-2b
A/4b    11/ 8/2085  B/4
A/4     03/19/2058  C.2b
A/4b     6/18/2051  B-2
A-4     03-01-2001  B-2b
A-4     02-14-2066  C-4
A/2     06/23/48    A-4
C-4b    18- 8-2065  B/2b
C-2     06-04-94    B/4
B/4b    2057/ 9/21  A-2b
C.2b    21. 8.31    A/2b
A/4b    11/13/2098  A/4
A/2     04/31/63    C-2
B/2b    22/ 5/ 7    A-2
C-4     11-09-2032  B/4b
C.4     08.05.2085  B-2
B-4     2038-10-22  C.4
A/2     03/09/37    C.2b
A/2b     4/ 9/21    A/4
C.2b     3.12.95    B-4
C-4b    26- 1-2004  C-2
```

As you can seem some dates or lines have random whitespaces... so how can i read in this input correctly with regex or any other reader? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming the position of the data in each line is always the same, read each line and then use `substring` and `trim` to get the data.

Comment: As you are using `Java`, then you are able to read the file line by line (such as `BufferedReader`). Now, if you wanted split the values from each line based on multiple white space, then used regex `\s+`, but what I am seeing here is that if you are using `\s+` to split values then you can expect wrong separate values on line, since there is white space on date value. So, you can used `\s{2,}` to split values on each line, that will get you expected result.

Comment: Splitting by space won't work because of the date values having spaces. If it can safely be assumed that the width of each column is the same for each line, you can use `substring` to extract each field, and `trim` to remove all surplus spaces (exactly as f1sh already said).

Answer (score 0):

Read each line in the file and then use regex "\s+"(character set of multiple white spaces) in split method to seperate them.

Edit: My bad, didn't notice space in date values. You can use "[ ]{2,}" as regex for 2 or more than 2 spaces.

Edit 2
This is full code to retrieve each data from file

```
public static void read(String fileName){
    //create file object
     File file = new File(fileName);
     
     //create file reader
    FileReader fileReader = null ;
    
    //define buffered reader
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null ;
    
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        
        String line;
        
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            
            //split lines into tokens (values) based on whitespace using regular expression "[ ]{2,}"
            //to indicate two ore more instances of whitespace
            String[] dataArray = line.trim().split("[ ]{2,}");
            
            
        
            //iterate over array of strings
            for(int i = 0 ; i< dataArray.length ; i++) {
                
                //get each value as a string
                String dateString = dataArray[i];
                if(i==1) {
                    System.out.println(dateString);
                }//prints out date in each line 
            }
        }   
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // gets and prints filename
        System.out.println("Sorry, " + file.getName() + " not found.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // prints the error message and info about which line
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        
        //regardless, close file objects
        try {
            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: That won't work as some of the date values in the middle column have spaces in them.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't notice that, but date only got one space at most so, we need to identify 2 or more white spaces. For that regex can be "[  ]{2,}".

Comment: @HimanshuSharma so is that the answer?

Comment: @Prome88 I thought you were just asking for regex. If you want full code I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution that works by just using the scanner. Some edge cases might fail but at least with the given input, and also with some variations of it, it seems to work fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {

    String input =
      "A-4     09-20-2083  B/2\nA/4     04/27/2048  C-2\nA/2b     1/24/75    A/4b\nA/4     05/07/2049  A/2b\nA/2b     7/ 3/31    B/2\nA/2b     5/11/53    B-4b\nC-4     14-07-2051  A/2\nC-2b    22-12-44    A/4\nC-4b    11-11-2055  C.2\nA/2b     5/11/16    C-2\nC.4     08.01.2058  A-4b\nB-4b    2010-11- 2  B/2b\nB/2b    26/ 3/13    A-4b\nC-2     18-06-06    B-4\nC.2     08.08.09    C-2\nA/2     01/20/99    B-2b\nC.4     18.08.2077  B/2\nA-4b    10-21-2086  B/4b\nB/2b    50/ 2/ 5    A/2\nA/4     03/08/2001  A-2b\nA/4b    11/ 8/2085  B/4\nA/4     03/19/2058  C.2b\nA/4b     6/18/2051  B-2\nA-4     03-01-2001  B-2b\nA-4     02-14-2066  C-4\nA/2     06/23/48    A-4\nC-4b    18- 8-2065  B/2b\nC-2     06-04-94    B/4\nB/4b    2057/ 9/21  A-2b\nC.2b    21. 8.31    A/2b\nA/4b    11/13/2098  A/4\nA/2     04/31/63    C-2\nB/2b    22/ 5/ 7    A-2\nC-4     11-09-2032  B/4b\nC.4     08.05.2085  B-2\nB-4     2038-10-22  C.4\nA/2     03/09/37    C.2b\nA/2b     4/ 9/21    A/4\nC.2b     3.12.95    B-4\nC-4b    26- 1-2004  C-2\n";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {

            String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();

            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            String[] filtered = Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);

            String first = filtered[0].trim ();
            String third = filtered[filtered.length - 1].trim();

            String[] dateArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(filtered, 1, filtered.length - 1);
            String second =  String.join("", dateArray);

            System.out.println (first + "||" + second + "||" + third);
    
   }

   scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need something fast to write...

```
String input = Files.readString(Path.of("path\\to\\your\\file.txt"));
//try-catch block omitted
Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(.+?)\\s*\n")
        .matcher(input)
        .results()
        .map(m -> {
            String firstGroupWithLetter = m.group(1);   //"A-4" from first line
            String date = m.group(2);                   //"09-20-2083"
            String secondGroupWithLetter = m.group(3);  //"B/2"
            // m.group(0) is reserved for full match result or kind of that

            // Do whatever you want
            return null;
        })
        // further actions
        ;
```